# Force update volume metadata for all songs in macOS Music App?

Tags: itunes, music

I am encountering an issue where many songs in my macOS Music app are missing volume information and therefore can't be sound checked (loudness normalization).

Under normal circumstances, as shown in the attached Image 1, songs do have volume information and can be sound checked.

[image]

However, a significant number of songs are (as shown in Image 2) missing volume information.

[image]

I suspect (although not certain) that this might be happening to music uploaded or added via Windows iTunes. All these songs seem to lack volume information. Is there a way to force the Music app to update volume information for all songs?